# Trying to download csv file using javascrpt and simulate click using .click() but what happens it isn't downloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code for exporting table data using javascript and jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
            var $headers = $table.find('tr:has(th)'),
                $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

                // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
                // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
                tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
                tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

                // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
                colDelim = '","',
                rowDelim = '"\r\n"';

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            var csv = '"';
                csv += formatRows($headers.map(grabRow));
                csv += rowDelim;
                csv += formatRows($rows.map(grabRow)) + '"';

                // Data URI
            var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

            $(this).attr({
                'download': filename,
                'href':     csvData
                // ,'target' : '_blank' //if you want it to open in a new window
            });

            //------------------------------------------------------------
            // Helper Functions
            //------------------------------------------------------------
            // Format the output so it has the appropriate delimiters
            function formatRows(rows) {
                return rows.get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                    .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                    .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim);
            }

            // Grab and format a row from the table
            function grabRow(i, row) {
                var $row = $(row);
                //for some reason $cols = $row.find('td') || $row.find('th') won't work...
                var $cols = $row.find('td');
                if (! $cols.length) $cols = $row.find('th');

                return $cols.map(grabCol).get().join(tmpColDelim);
            }

            // Grab and format a column from the table
            function grabCol(j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                    $text = $col.text();

                return $text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes
            }
        }

        // This must be a hyperlink
        $("#export").click(function (event) {
            // var outputFile = 'export'
            // var outputFile = window.prompt(
            //     "What do you want to name your output file (Note: This won't have any effect on Safari)"
            // ) || 'export';

            // outputFile = outputFile.replace('.csv', '') + '.csv'
            outputFile = 'export.csv';

            // CSV
            exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), outputFile]);

            // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
            // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
        });

        $("#export").click();
    });
```

this code come from here https://gist.github.com/adilapapaya/9787842 but I added `$("#export").click();` on the end to simulate click, but what happens it isn't downloading the `csv` file when I refresh the page.

It should download the moment I refresh the page, but it doesn't.

Can you explain why and How may I solve this?

---

Found the solution myself

```
        function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {
            var $headers = $table.find('tr:has(th)'),
                $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

                // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
                // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
                tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
                tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

                // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
                colDelim = '","',
                rowDelim = '"\r\n"';

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            var csv = '"';
                csv += formatRows($headers.map(grabRow));
                csv += rowDelim;
                csv += formatRows($rows.map(grabRow)) + '"';

                // Data URI
            var csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

            // Added this line
            var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

            $(hiddenElement).attr({
                'download': filename,
                'href':     csvData,
                'target' : '_blank' //if you want it to open in a new window
            });

            // and this line
            hiddenElement.click();

            //------------------------------------------------------------
            // Helper Functions
            //------------------------------------------------------------
            // Format the output so it has the appropriate delimiters
            function formatRows(rows) {
                return rows.get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim);
            }

            // Grab and format a row from the table
            function grabRow(i, row) {
                var $row = $(row);
                //for some reason $cols = $row.find('td') || $row.find('th') won't work...
                var $cols = $row.find('td');
                if (! $cols.length) $cols = $row.find('th');

                return $cols.map(grabCol).get().join(tmpColDelim);
            }

            // Grab and format a column from the table
            function grabCol(j, col) {
                var $col = $(col),
                $text = $col.text();

                return $text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes
            }
        }


        outputFile = 'export.csv';
        exportTableToCSV($('#dvData > table'), outputFile);
```

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: `$("#export").click();`. I assume this is a button or similar, that will fire a function. Why not just fire the function directly? Why go through the process of simulating a click?

Comment: i tried it first, but no luck, here's the code. `outputFile = 'fil.csv';` `exportTableToCSV.apply(null, [$('#dvData > table'), outputFile]);` What i done here is the second option